# Baruch hu u'varuch shemo or Baruch Shemo?

Tags: blessing

It says in all the seforim (e.g. [Orach Chayim 124:5](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%94)) that one says "Baruch hu u'varuch shemo."  But some people say "Baruch Shemo" instead.  Is either one correct halachically, or only the former?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I think it's probably just people swallowing their words

Comment: Only the former,the formulation is based off the Rishonim. It seems like it's a simple mistake ppl make,maybe because it sounds similar to the original.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like most are saying just "Shmo".

Comment: Amongst people who do not enunciate the former, I hear "Baruch hmbmashMO" or some such. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

@cookieson03. The author of the Torah Temimah, Harav Baruch Epstein zl, in his Sefer Boruch She'omar on tfillah (page 114, this part of the sefer not available on hebrewbooks.org) writes that he was told that many people stopped saying "Baruch hu varuch shemo" as its gematriya is 814 which is the same as the gematriya of "Shabtai Zvi" and his followers ardently undertook to mention it to commemorate him. He points out that this gematriya is only true without the "vav" of "uvaruch" and advises to make sure to say it with the "vav".
I once heard that this might be the source of people saying "Baruch Shemo".

Comment: Very nice "limmud zechus"

Comment: Interesting historical take. I wasn't aware of any shabbateans that still exist though

Comment: Dönmeh still exist. And Freemasons have some Frankist origins

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Lieberman [writes](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/6988)

> "It is brought in the tur in the name of his father the "Rosh"= Rabbeinu Asher who explains the reason for saying Baruch hu u’varuch Shemo is in response to the saying the name of Hashem as expressed in the Passuk (Devarim 32:3) When I call out Hasem's name praise God for his greatness". (See Tur
> and Shulchan Aruch 124) The Kabbalists also attributed great
> importance saying to Baruch hu u’varuch Shemo correctly. (כף החיים סי'
> ה ס"ק יב.)  Unfortunately as you said many people say it  incorrectly
> because of the way they have it heard it from others. When you think
> of it, it's one of the few parts of prayer which everyone knows you
> are supposed to say it, but it most siddurim it is just not printed.
> So people without giving much thought to what they are saying continue
> to say it the incorrect way and some others swallow their words since
> they are not  used to speaking in Hebrew.

It would seem baruch hu u'baruch shemo is the correct form, and any deviation - like baruch shmo - should be changed.